# Can iframes protect their contents from outside JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, security, iframe

Iframes are known for sandboxing the JavaScript *inside* the iframe. But, is the converse true? Do iframes protect their contents from JavaScript *outside* (on the hosting webpage)? My basic tests suggest that they do, but I can't find explicit documentation on this.

If you're curious, here's my use case:

> A browser extension must display sensitive text on a third-party, untrusted webpage. Ideally, it will inject the text such that it cannot be accessed by JavaScript running on the untrusted webpage. The user may see it; the JavaScript may not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mechanisms for separating the JavaScript environments of the parent document and the iframed document work the same way in both directions.

- They have their own environments
- Access to the other environment is possible via `parent` and `frameNode` if they contain documents that are on the same origin
- `postMessage` can be used to pass strings between them even if they are not on the same origin (but must be listened for by the document receiving the message).

> A browser extension must display sensitive text on a third-party, untrusted webpage. Ideally, it will inject the text such that it cannot be accessed by JavaScript running on the untrusted webpage. The user may see it; the JavaScript may not.

This sounds like something better addressed using a mechanism that displays the text in the browser chrome rather than embedded in the page itself, e.g. with the Chrome [popup api](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#popups).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I think my case still requires the iframe because I'm actually replacing existing elements of the webpage with sensitive text.Though I'll probably use the popup eventually, these iframes are supposed to replace actual elements inside web pages.

Answer (score -1):

As best I can tell, the content is protected.

Iframes' contents are ([by default](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp)) treated as if from a different origin. This brings the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) into play, preventing each page from accessing the others' DOM.

However, if you do `<iframe sandbox="allow-same-origin">...</iframe>`), then the iframe's contents can be accessed. Here's an important question:

- **Can malicious JavaScript programmatically set `allow-same-origin` to get into an iframe**?

I don't know of explicit documentation on this, but my tests in Google Chrome say that *programmatically* changing the sandbox attribute has no effect on the iframe. Yes, you can dynamically change the `sandbox` attribute, but it has no effect.